# Windows 10 sleeps fine from menu, won't sleep from timeout

Tags: windows-10, motherboard, sleep, power, energy-saving

I have a power meter on a Windows 10 box.  If I sleep from the menu or the power button, it drops down to about 3 watts.  If I wait for a timeout (set at two minutes) it blanks the screen but keeps using the same amount of power.

I've noticed that browser tabs with videos or ads, even if paused will block sleep.  But closing those is not enough, there's something about the network:

```
C:\Windows\system32>powercfg -requests
DISPLAY:    None.

SYSTEM:    [DRIVER] \FileSystem\srvnet
An active remote client has recently sent requests to this machine.

AWAYMODE:    None.

EXECUTION:    None.

PERFBOOST:    None.
```

This is a newly installed machine with a major brand motherboard.  No specific file sharing is in use, there are no other windows machines on the local network.  How can I get this machine to automatically sleep based on the timer?  Which "remote client" might the problem be?

I have read the old thread https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/784f203d-0103-4272-8884-e4d4834b11db/sleep-blocked-by-active-remote-client?forum=w7itprogeneral
See similar questions each with less detail:
[Windows 10 won't sleep, even after overriding drivers](https://superuser.com/questions/1050924/windows-10-wont-sleep-even-after-overriding-drivers) and [Windows 10 PCs not sleeping after automatic wake (sometimes)](https://superuser.com/questions/966976/windows-10-pcs-not-sleeping-after-automatic-wake-sometimes?rq=1) and [Windows 10 doesn't sleep](https://superuser.com/questions/1060085/windows-10-doesnt-sleep)

Comment: Do you have Wake on Lan enabled?

Comment: Wake on lan is not enabled.

Comment: Try `powercfg -requestsoverride DRIVER srvnet system` and `powercfg -requestsoverride DRIVER \FileSystem\srvnet system`

Comment: @DavidPostill that has no effect, either on the current boot, nor on subsequent boots.  How can one verify those have taken effect?  How can one disable those overrides after application?

Comment: @Bryce add information about power button. I guess that power button pressing will also provide you a proper sleep. It means that it is sleep-on-timeout problem. It just shuts down the screen on the timeout instead of proper sleep that I also connected to the power button.

Comment: Which edition of Windows do you have? Can you try [Allow Applications to Prevent Automatic Sleep](https://www.google.ee/search?q=Allow+Applications+to+Prevent+Automatic+Sleep)

Comment: Windows 10 retail.